# Failing to print metrics with Kafka consumer performance test

Tags: java, apache-kafka, performance-testing

When I run the `kafka-consumer-perf-test.sh` with the `--print-metrics` flag

```
bin/kafka-consumer-perf-test --topic kafka-performance-topic  --messages 100000  --broker-list <MY-KAFKA>  --consumer.config config.properties --print-metrics
```

The script prints only a few metrics and then returns an error

```
consumer-fetch-manager-metrics:fetch-rate:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-79651-1}                                                          : 1,102
consumer-fetch-manager-metrics:fetch-size-avg:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-79651-1, topic=kafka-performance-topic}                       : 2153002,766
consumer-fetch-manager-metrics:fetch-size-avg:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-79651-1}                                                      : 2153002,766
consumer-fetch-manager-metrics:fetch-size-max:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-79651-1, topic=kafka-performance-topic}                       : 4132864,000
consumer-fetch-manager-metrics:fetch-size-max:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-79651-1}                                                      : 4132864,000
consumer-fetch-manager-metrics:fetch-throttle-time-avg:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-79651-1}                                             : 0,000
consumer-fetch-manager-metrics:fetch-throttle-time-max:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-79651-1}                                             : 0,000
consumer-fetch-manager-metrics:fetch-total:{client-id=consumer-perf-consumer-79651-1}                                                         : 48,000
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.Integer
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4426)
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Formatter.java:2951)
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2898)
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2673)
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2609)
        at java.base/java.lang.String.format(String.java:2897)
        at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.format(StringLike.scala:354)
        at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.format$(StringLike.scala:353)
        at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.format(StringOps.scala:33)
        at kafka.utils.ToolsUtils$.$anonfun$printMetrics$3(ToolsUtils.scala:60)
        at kafka.utils.ToolsUtils$.$anonfun$printMetrics$3$adapted(ToolsUtils.scala:58)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at kafka.utils.ToolsUtils$.printMetrics(ToolsUtils.scala:58)
        at kafka.tools.ConsumerPerformance$.main(ConsumerPerformance.scala:82)
        at kafka.tools.ConsumerPerformance.main(ConsumerPerformance.scala)
```